# Touchable address to launch maps app. What is recommended?

Tags: hyperlinks, maps, geolocation

Has anyone done testing over what best to display with an address that indicates when it is touched can launch a maps app (this is for a mobile app)? Do you use a Google style pin? Apple style Pin? Apple Location style Icon? Underlined text? Different icon for different OS?

Curious whether or not someone has done research on this. Have seen research on the 'hamburger/menu' icon so didn't think this question was too unusual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i haven't though setting up a usera or amazon mechnical turk will get you the results you want quickly. You can just show them the google map icon (the droplet thing) and ask them to type in a box what they think it is.

or put 4 icons up and tell them to click the one they think would open the map.

i would assume something like this [image] would do better than the little apple pin or googles droplet . Though that might be too bulky.

Actually a better test to run would be to have 4 icons (3 of them are static , i.e. safari email calendar and two map icons.) and say select the icon for the maps. put different designs against each other. design in parallel for best results.

Answer (score 0):

As a user, I've seen apps marking address as a hyperlink which launches Maps app. If you take a closer look at iOS Mail app or Messages app, if someone sends you a location, it is simply underlined.

I don't understand why it should be any different that a link. It's a hyperlink to launching another app, if you think about it.